# Finding eigenvalues from substituted charasteristic polynomial

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find eigenvalues of a 5x5 matrix of rang 4 with long symbolic expressions in all elements.

Can I substitute matrix elements with letters A-Z, express the characteristic polynomial to find its roots and, finally, substitute back the original expressions for the letters?

I'm in a dilemma as I've received a negative answer, as the characteristic polynomial has a degree 5 and its roots cannot be expressed in the form of radicals and a conditional yes, if the eigenvalues are distinct.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Well, if the rank is 4, it means that $0$ is an eigenvalue, and that the characteristic polynomial has the form $XP(X)$, with $P$ of degree $4$. But you can compute (in theory) the roots of polynomials of degree $4$ (Ferrari's method)...

Comment: The thing is the elements are large expressions with 15 variables and so far commands Roots, Eigenvalues or JordanDecomposition haven't produced any result in a day or so. Besides substitution I'm not sure how many other options are there.